# Origen de la expresión "efectos especiales"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, significado

Hay varias expresiones en las que se incluye la palabra **efecto** en las que se entiende que un "efecto" es algo producido por una causa. Por ejemplo "efecto invernadero" o "efecto dominó".

Pero me cuesta entender por qué se llaman **efectos especiales** los trucos computacionales o de tramoya que se usan en el cine. ¿Es "la misma" palabra *efecto* o tiene otro origen?

Comment: Nótese que [efecto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EOoHYxJ) tiene múltiples acepciones. Inicialmente pensé en que es una traducción literal del inglés "special effects", pero mirando el [n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=efectos+especiales&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cefectos%20especiales%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Befectos%20especiales%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEfectos%20especiales%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEFECTOS%20ESPECIALES%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEfectos%20Especiales%3B%2Cc0) veo que es algo que se utiliza desde hace casi 200 años

Comment: No encuentro ninguna página que corrobore lo que aparece en la Wikipedia pero a mi parecer es un claro anglicismo:
*Con el tiempo el anglicismo efecto especial (del inglés special effect) ha ido reemplazando al galicismo [trucaje](http://dle.rae.es/?w=trucar) (del francés trucage), que hasta tiempos relativamente recientes era el más utilizado en lengua española.*

Comment: @fedorqui Investigando un poco con los resultados de n-gram veo que los libros del siglo XIX que mencionan _efectos especiales_ son de medicina, derecho, administración... Nada que ver con el cine (lógico, por las fechas). Parecen menciones a cosas que tienen "efectos" distintos a otras cosas, _especiales_. En los tratados médicos diría que se refieren a efectos secundarios de tratamientos, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, como han apuntado AlexBcn, fedorqui, MikMik y aparente001, *efectos especiales* es un anglicismo. Proviene del inglés *special effects*, donde "effect" significa "sensación" o "impresión dejada en el espíritu" (en Wiktionary, [effect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effect#Noun), acepción 2). La misma definición existe también en español (en DRAE, [efecto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EOoHYxJ), acepción 2).

Entonces los "efectos especiales" no son "consecuencias especiales" sino "sensaciones especiales".

Su origen es latino: del participio "*effectus*" (completado, cumplido), que a su vez se forma a partir de la raíz "*facere*" (hacer) y el prefijo "*ex*" (afuera). Originalmente, entonces, se refería al "resultado de completar algo" (en [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?efecto)).

Tanto en inglés (a través del francés antiguo) como en español, su significado original evolucionó por un lado directamente a "consecuencia", y por otro a "sensación", entendiendo que las sensaciones son lo que se produce en el espíritu como *resultado* de un estímulo percibido.

Y en este caso se puede oponer el concepto de *sensación* al de *realidad*, cuando los sentidos nos ofrecen percepciones engañosas. Este valor de "percepción falsa" es el que predomina tanto en "efectos especiales" como en el "efecto" dado a la pelota cuando un puntapié bien dado curva su trayectoria. Y por último, el mismo sentido se puede encontrar en el adjetivo peyorativo "efectista" dado a un discurso o una obra.

Answer (score 1):

Le daría razón a @MikMik, que "efectos especiales" es sencillamente una traducción de "special effects."  Porque en los textos modernos y las conversaciones, observo que las dos frases se usan en el mismísimo contexto, para expresar la mismísima idea.

Y a mi aviso, no se limita al cine.  Podríamos poner efectos especiales a una obra de teatro también.  Es un truco técnico que crea una ilusión en la percepción del público.

Aunque sí, es más común en el cine y video que en el teatro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Para que ésta quede más completa, te sugeriría que incluyeras el significado de la palabra "effect" y, si es posible, si tiene alguna relación con la palabra española "efecto".